# Javadocs are not appearing on Apache netbeans for java 10

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc, java-10

Netbeans Version: Apache NetBeans 9.0

Java version: Java 10

No matter what I do, I can't get the javadocs to appear and display method details on anything.

I've gone into the Java Platforms and into the Javadocs, I've set the Zip, unzipped and URL for the javadocs, but it just wont work...

Java Doc: jdk-10.0.1_doc-all

URL: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api

I couldn't find any answers anywhere, they all mentioned adding the docs like I already tried.

Edit Reply:
Even with adding the 'java.base/' it still doesn't work. I even completely deleted netbeans and all appdata. Re-downloaded it, installed JDK11, and tried the docs again...but the SAME thing. Am I going insane??

[image]
[image]

Comment: What’s jumping into my eye, is that the usual frameset does not appear with that link. In the browser, I can fix that using [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/?overview-summary.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/?overview-summary.html), but I doubt that Netbeans will interpret Javascript for these pages, so that won’t help here.

Comment: @Holger, I tried that too, but it didn't change anything. I left it at 'api' because that's how it was in all the other versions.

Comment: [1] NetBeans 9.0 does not support Java 11, so you should have no expectation of that working. [2] However, to be clear, did you first try Java 10 using the same approach as Java 11 in your updated question? [3] What platform are you running on?

Comment: @Skomisa, yes I tried this same approach with Java 10 and 9. I'm on win10

Comment: @DrakeWalker I have updated my answer to address the use of OpenJDK 10 with NB 9.0. Strangely, Javadocs for Java 10 methods work _even though I did not even specify a Javadoc location_ when adding **OpenJDK 10** as a Java Platform. So perhaps try doing what I did in my updated answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link to the JDK help documentation in NetBeans using a URL or the file location of the zipped documentation. Both approaches work for me for Java 10 using 
Apache NetBeans 9.0 RC1:

[image: javadocLinks]

Obviously you only need one of those entries. Both are shown in the screen shot above purely for addressing your question, and both can be set during the addition of the JDK 10 platform, or at a later time.

For using the file location for JDK Javadocs:

- [Download the Javadoc files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk10-doc-downloads-4417029.html) to some arbitrary directory.
- **Tools > Java Platforms > Javadoc** tab **> {your jdk 10 platform} > Add ZIP/folder...**
- Navigate to the downloaded Javadoc file, which was **jdk-10-ea+42_doc-all.zip** in my case.

For using the URL for JDK Javadocs:

- **Tools > Java Platforms > Javadoc** tab **> {your jdk 10 platform} >  Add URL...**
- Add the URL, which was https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/ in my case.

If you still have problems:

- Make sure that you are using the [latest build of NetBeans 9.0 RC1](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html).
- Use the specific URL and Javadoc file that I used, since both approaches definitely work for me.
- If things still aren't working delete the JDK 10 platform, restart NetBeans and try again. (I have no specific reason for suggesting that, but it will only take two minutes to try.)

My personal preference is to use a local zip file rather than a URL since it is faster and you do not need internet access. Here's a screen shot showing the Javadoc for **Optional.orElseThrow()** which was new in JDK10:

[image: orElseThrow()]

---

**Updated on 11/8/2018** to address the use of OpenJDK 10 with NB 9.0:

- I deleted all Java Platforms except **JDK 1.8 (Default)**.
- I closed NetBeans and deleted the cache and user directories as shown in **Help > About**.
- I restarted NetBeans and created a trivial Java application that called **Optional.orElseThrow()** which was added in JDK 10. As expected the project would not compile using the platform **JDK 1.8 (Default)**.
- I added **OpenJDK 10** as a Java platform, *but did not specify any Javadoc*.

  [image: AddPlatform]
  [image: NoJavaDoc]
- I updated the project to use **OpenJDK 10** instead of **JDK 1.8 (Default)**. Help for Java 10 methods worked fine without specifying any Javadoc location!

  [image: HelpForOpenJDK10]

Comment: This is already what I tried. I tried using only the URL, ZIP, Folder, and a combination of them, but nothing works. I tried redownloading java and Netbeans (which is the portable zip; latest version), but the new netbeans also brought up my installed theme, and already had the same zip install and URL for the javadocs as the other netbeans zip I downloaded, meaning that its storing those somewhere else...probably Appdata? Either way, the javadocs do not appear. Another thing I noticed is that netbeans will randomly give me null pointer and file not found messages when coding.

Comment: I just cleared my appdata files for netbeans, and downloaded the Netbeans beta, but it STILL doesn't work....

Comment: I am working with Netbeans 9.0 (incubator-netbeans-release-334-on-20180708 and openjdk-11-jdk (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.3)) and the problem is also there visible. It seems, that file resources are not handled in proper way. It also concerns debugging (step into library code, when `src.zip` is configured as file resource).

Comment: I have created the [Netbeans issue 1591](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1591)

Comment: @ManfredSteiner [1] Interesting. This definitely worked for me, as my screen shot shows. [2] I will try with OpenJDK instead of Oracle JDK later. [3] FYI, although it works for me in limited testing, I don't think NB 9.0 officially supports JDK 11; that's coming with NB 10. [4] Also, I am using Windows, not Ubuntu, though I don't see why that should matter for this issue.

Comment: I just edited my original post, please take a look when you can.

Comment: @ManfredSteiner [1] I updated my answer when using OpenJDK 10 with NB 9.0. Javadoc help works for me without even specifying a Javadoc location. [2] Perhaps raise a separate question (and/or NetBeans bug) if you still have issues with debugging when using JDK 10 or less with NB 9.0.

Comment: @skomisa FYI, I ended up going to ubuntu and using NB 9.0 over there with Java 8 and it seems to work. I never got it to work with the updated answers on windows 10...Not sure what was going on or why it was acting up, but even Java 8 wasn't showing on windows 10...

Comment: @DrakeWalker Heh...you can't understand why it's failing for you, and I can't understand why it's working for me! Anyway, glad it worked for you in the end.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is caused by missing the `java.base/` on the end of the locator.

`java.base`, starting with Java 9, is the definition of the foundational APIs of the Java SE platform.

Using `https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/` as URL resource will fail.
Using `https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/` as URL resource will work.

Same issue for file resources. Add `java.base/` at the end of the former file locator and it works.

Comment: I just edited my original post, please take a look when you can.

Comment: That url works for me too, but if the Javadoc is on a local drive it does not work, for example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\docs\api\java.base does not work.

Comment: It took me months to get to that answer which eventually solved the missing java doc on my Netbeans 11 under Debian 11! Adding `java.base/` as suggested did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem with Apache Netbeans 9 and JDK 11. Whatever I did, I could not see Javadoc results in Netbeans. I did succeed in the end. The steps I undertook:

- I downloaded the jdk-11.0.1_doc-all.zip file.
- The downloaded file I saved in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\docs
- In Netbeans under Tools -> Java Platform, under tab "Javadoc", I added the location of the folder C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\docs

The above steps did not help me, but after I restarted Netbeans64 with "Run as Administrator", it worked like a charm. Maybe something to do with security settings?

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this same issue using Apache Netbeans 9 and JDK 11 and this worked for me.  If you need the swing components you have to add java.desktop as well.  Also, you must have the trailing / for the online resource to work.  You think they would check for that and add it if it doesn't exist.

online resource

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/

local resource unzipped in Ubuntu /opt/jdk/ folder

/opt/jdk/jdk-11.0.1_doc-all/docs/api/java.base

/opt/jdk/jdk-11.0.1_doc-all/docs/api/java.desktop

Comment: I had the same issue in Netbeans 11 and OpenJDK 11. Unzipping the javadocs and pointing netbeans to the java.base folder fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

For Netbeans on **Linux-Mint** and **Java version 11** this work for me

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-doc

sudo apt install openjdk-11-source
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the jdk from 11 to 8, then configured the suitable Java 8 doc folder. This solved the problem. You have to change the project too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after fighting a lot with NB 11 and OpenJDK 11 Javadoc, I fix it!

Platform: Ubuntu 18.04
Apache NetBeans IDE 11.0 (Build incubator-netbeans-release-404-on-20190319

I could not get to work the javadoc with any of the previous listed method. No HTTP, or local. Nothing work, or partially work. :(
But, just in the last minute, when I already felt defeated and was about to jump to ECLIPSE, I think: what about OracleJDK 11?. It's suppose to be the same but...
I downloaded the JDK11 from Oracle, uncompress it in a folder and add it as a Java Platform in NB and voila! It's work! 
It have nothing in Javadoc tab, but it recognize the src and everything is working. I use that platform only for typing since I build everything from console with gradle and the OpenJDK.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian/Ubuntu:

```
apt install openjdk-11-doc
```

Then add go to:

**Tools > Java Platforms > Javadoc tab > {your jdk 11 platform} > Add ZIP/Folder...**:

```
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/java.base
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem in my case (Ubuntu 19) immediately after a restart of NB:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-13-source
```