# Can't see javadoc information. How do I fix it?

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc, netbeans-11

Can't see Javadoc information.

"Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc documentation for this item does not exist or you have not added specified Javadoc in the Java Platform Manager or the Library Manager."

[image: Sreenshot of error]

My Java platform:

[image: JavaPlatform]

Javadocs in Java platform:

[image: JavadocsInJavaPlatform]

I tried downloading the Javadoc, adding it to my Platform Manager. Nothing works.

IDE LOGS:
    `Here is the logs` https://pastebin.com/dPNx9dJm

Netbeans 11.2 IDE, running Java 13.0.1

Others in the github project have same setup, and they have Javadocs working. (They can see the method descriptions/documentation)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I fix it?

Comment: Fix what? We don't even know what you're trying to do.

Comment: @LowKeyEnergy Pretty sure OP is trying to see the Javadocs for built-in methods.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please, could you provide more information about the version of Netbeans that you are using? thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I want to see the descriptions of the methods etc.

Comment: Netbeans 11.2 @JaimeS And Java 13

Comment: Just google the name of the method.

Comment: I want it to work on netbeans. It enhances workflow

Comment: Your question is too vague as it stands. You need to add information to your question: Java version, NetBeans version, how did you create the project (Maven, Ant, Gradle, etc.), project type (Java application, Spring application, web application, etc.), does this problem exist in all your projects?, screenshots of your Java Platform tabs, relevant content in NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**), etc. Provide enough information so that others can try to replicate your problem. Because there are several _potential causes_ for your problem, without more details any responses would just be guesses.

Comment: See [Netbeans v11.2 and Oracle JDK13 javadocs issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58886235/2985643). There is no solution, and the problem is not identical to yours (it is less severe), but it may be helpful. Also see [Netbeans 11 Javadoc Not Appearing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56161666/2985643).

Comment: @LowKeyEnergy Suggesting that the OP uses google instead is not helpful or constructive. Showing javadocs is basic functionality within NetBeans, and is very widely used to display version specific documentation.

Comment: @skomisa I have now added the information you requested

Comment: @KryoZeric [1] This is working for me with Java 13 on NetBeans 11.2, but if I try to replicate your problem on my machine, how should I create my project? [2] I downloaded the Javadocs for JDK 13 separately, and specified that zip file (`"D:\Downloads\Java\Java13\jdk-13.0.1_doc-all.zip"` in my case) instead, so you might try that. That said, I see nothing wrong with your approach. [3] There is a bug report for this issue. See [Netbeans does not handle platform javadoc for jdk 10+](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2624), though I think it greatly overstates the issue's severity.

Comment: It's simply just "new project", Java with Ant, then Java Application. Everything is setup exactly like everyone else from my class. My teacher even said it was setup normally. I seems like no matter how the project is created it still doesnt show. I have tried just using the ZIP, but unfortuantly doesnt work

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wt51i0wn

My IDE log, after changing some library settings under the project im in. Getting all sorts of errors and catches. Saying something in Java 13 lib missing. And I can't right click my project anymore to select properties. It just does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I ended up finding a pretty easy fix:

Reinstall the Java version, then delete the old path in system environment. And then put it back in. The path should be something like: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\bin
Mine was: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\

After I did this, it fixed it. I think it was my environment path which was wrong.

1. Windows+R
2. systempropertiesadvanced
3. Environment variables
4. Under system variables, put under path the path to your Java BIN folder

Comment: It's good that you have everything working now, but I am a bit surprised at your resolution. As far as I know NetBeans doesn't care about your **PATH** environment variable because it gets the JDK information it needs from the _Java Platform Manager_ settings, and from your screen shots it looks like you had set everything up properly. In my case I successfully use Java 13 in NetBeans, including its Javadocs, but it is not on my **PATH**.

Comment: @skomisa Then it probably also helped just reinstalling my Java 13 I think. I just wanted to document everything I did in the answer, incase someone with the same problem needs it.

Comment: OK, cool. I agree that there was probably some glitch associated with the previous installation, or at least I can't see that there was anything else wrong with what you had originally done.