# Netbeans 12.3 Can't See Javadoc Despite URL Set?

Tags: netbeans, javadoc

I'm using Netbeans 12.3 (Manjaro Linux, system specs later in the post), but can't seem to get Javadoc to appear for core classes.
[image]

I have the URL set in platform manager, but a `clean & build` or `generate javadoc` does nothing.
[image]

Here is the Netbeans readout:

[image]

**System Specs:**

> ```
> System:
>   Host: MidnightStarSign Kernel: 5.10.34-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc 
>   v: 10.2.0 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.21.4 Distro: Manjaro Linux base: Arch Linux 
> Machine:
>   Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: PRIME X570-PRO v: Rev X.0x 
>   serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 3001 
>   date: 12/04/2020 
> CPU:
>   Info: 16-Core model: AMD Ryzen 9 5950X bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen 3 
>   rev: 0 cache: L2: 8 MiB 
>   flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm 
>   bogomips: 217607 
>   Speed: 4161 MHz min/max: 2200/3400 MHz boost: enabled Core speeds (MHz): 
>   1: 4161 2: 4738 3: 2880 4: 2911 5: 2906 6: 2949 7: 2880 8: 2910 9: 3931 
>   10: 4610 11: 3874 12: 3866 13: 3876 14: 4432 15: 4829 16: 3877 17: 3870 
>   18: 2880 19: 3621 20: 2959 21: 2879 22: 2880 23: 2880 24: 3874 25: 2879 
>   26: 3148 27: 4143 28: 4838 29: 3864 30: 3868 31: 3021 32: 3717 
> Graphics:
>   Device-1: NVIDIA GA104 [GeForce RTX 3070] vendor: ASUSTeK driver: nvidia 
>   v: 460.73.01 bus-ID: 0a:00.0 
>   Device-2: Microdia USB 2.0 Camera type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo 
>   bus-ID: 7-1:2 
>   Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: nvidia resolution: 
>   1: 1920x1080 2: 1920x1080 3: 1920x1080 
>   OpenGL: renderer: GeForce RTX 3070/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 460.73.01 
>   direct render: Yes 
> Audio:
>   Device-1: NVIDIA vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
>   bus-ID: 0a:00.1 
>   Device-2: AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel 
>   v: kernel bus-ID: 0c:00.4 
>   Device-3: JMTek LLC. Plugable USB Audio Device type: USB 
>   driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus-ID: 3-1:2 
>   Device-4: Schiit Audio Schiit Modi 3+ type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio 
>   bus-ID: 3-2:3 
>   Device-5: ASUSTek ASUS AI Noise-Cancelling Mic Adapter type: USB 
>   driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus-ID: 5-5:3 
>   Device-6: Microdia USB 2.0 Camera type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo 
>   bus-ID: 7-1:2 
>   Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.10.34-1-MANJARO running: yes 
>   Sound Server-2: JACK v: 0.125.0 running: no 
>   Sound Server-3: PulseAudio v: 14.2 running: yes 
>   Sound Server-4: PipeWire v: 0.3.26 running: yes 
> Network:
>   Device-1: Intel I211 Gigabit Network vendor: ASUSTeK driver: igb v: kernel 
>   port: f000 bus-ID: 06:00.0 
>   IF: enp6s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 24:4b:fe:5b:08:2a 
> Bluetooth:
>   Device-1: Cambridge Silicon Radio Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode) type: USB 
>   driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 3-5.3:6 
>   Report: rfkill ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: see --recommends 
> Drives:
>   Local Storage: total: 3.78 TiB used: 1.82 TiB (48.1%) 
>   ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital model: WDS100T3X0C-00SJG0 
>   size: 931.51 GiB temp: 48.9 C 
>   ID-2: /dev/nvme1n1 vendor: Western Digital model: WDS100T2B0C-00PXH0 
>   size: 931.51 GiB temp: 41.9 C 
>   ID-3: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST2000LM015-2E8174 size: 1.82 TiB 
>   ID-4: /dev/sdb type: USB vendor: Samsung model: Flash Drive FIT 
>   size: 119.51 GiB 
>   ID-5: /dev/sdc type: USB vendor: Toshiba model: TransMemory size: 14.92 GiB 
>   ID-6: /dev/sdd type: USB vendor: SanDisk model: Gaming Xbox 360 size: 7.48 GiB 
> Partition:
>   ID-1: / size: 767 GiB used: 745.17 GiB (97.2%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/dm-0 
>   mapped: luks-466d5812-64c7-4a28-bcc4-a1a5adfa9450 
>   ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 26.1 MiB (5.1%) fs: vfat 
>   dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 
>   ID-3: /home size: 767 GiB used: 745.17 GiB (97.2%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/dm-0 
>   mapped: luks-466d5812-64c7-4a28-bcc4-a1a5adfa9450 
> Swap:
>   ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 64 GiB used: 3.2 MiB (0.0%) dev: /dev/dm-1 
>   mapped: luks-81b2dc57-06f5-4471-b484-77c3a516f307 
> Sensors:
>   System Temperatures: cpu: 55.5 C mobo: 0 C gpu: nvidia temp: 40 C 
>   Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 0% 
> Info:
>   Processes: 818 Uptime: 2d 15h 11m Memory: 62.79 GiB used: 27.82 GiB (44.3%) 
>   Init: systemd Compilers: gcc: 10.2.0 clang: 11.1.0 Packages: 1963 Shell: Bash 
>   v: 5.1.4 inxi: 3.3.04
> ```

How can I get the Javadoc to display properly?

Comment: This works fine for me using NetBeans 12.3 and JDK 15.0.2, but there are two differences between us: [1] I am on Windows 10 and you are on Linux. I'm not sure why that might matter, but see [Javadocs are not appearing on Apache netbeans for java 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51182338/2985643) for a very similar scenario with earlier releases of NetBeans/Java. [2] My javadoc URL is not quite the same as yours. I don't have **index.html** at the end of the path, so try removing that to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Another approach is to download the javadoc as a zip file, and unzip it locally. Then provide a filepath to the local Javadoc in NetBeans instead of the https link. The problem with this approach is that I don't see how to download the JDK 15 Javadoc as a zip! That used to be easy but not any more apparently.

Comment: @skomisa Thanks a bunch! That answer resolved my issue!

Comment: OK, but could you post an answer stating what actually fixed your problem? That's much more helpful to the community than just commenting that the issue is resolved.